# I have error here with "flet build apk --verbose "

Tags: build, apk, flet

It shows in terminal (usage: flet [-h] [--version] {create,run,pack,publish} ... flet: error: unrecognized arguments: apk)

Can anybody Have any solution. I have install android studio and as well as flutter i have set up all path variable too.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade the flet package with pip.

```
pip install flet --upgrade
```

The **flet build apk** command works after I update the package to the latest version (0.19.0).